# how do i get the xp drivers for broadcom WiFi?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, wireless-networking, broadcom

i have an acer aspire 5732z notebook and i am installing windows xp on it.
i got all the drivers but i couldnt find the wireless driver.
i used http://www.pcidatabase.com/search.php?device_search_str=4357&device_search.x=44&device_search.y=4 and found out that the wireless card is broadcom.
but i couldnt find anywhere to download the driver.
any help?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you try here:

http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/downloaddrivers.php

too bad the acer website doesn't provide windows xp drivers.

Comment: there is no drivers on broadcom.com page. i cheked it

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one thinking that

Comment: i saw it there... its just kinda hidden

http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/netxtreme_desktop.php

Here's the link i was thinking... perhaps this is only for wired NIC cards, but its worth a try.

Comment: this looks like its for wired. i didnt ever see a wireless network driver that is 129KB

Comment: NetXtreme Ethernet controllers: this is no way wifi

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Driver Max](http://www.drivermax.com/) website...have used them before - the only caveat is that you can only download one (i think!) free driver per day, so choose carefully...

They have a lot of older drivers, and many users contribute drivers...worth a look!

Answer (score 0):

Go here and download this driver package from Dell, use winzip or other utility to unpack the exe  file, then use device manager to install the driver manually, point it to the "DRIVER" folder of the unpacked contents. see if it will work for you.

If given the choice of download method after clicking "Download" button, use your Browser.

[Click Me](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R140745&SystemID=LAT_PNT_PM_D600&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&deviceid=6482&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=22&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=5&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=187888)